# Web Sockets on Samsung Galaxy S3 Android Browser?

Tags: android, websocket, galaxy

So, apparently the webapp we did, that uses websockets, does not work on the Samsung Galaxy S3 stock Android browser. The thing is, Android Browser is not supposed to have web sockets support, but it looks like this one has, although the websockets don't work, the connection takes forever and never succeeds.
Our webapp has a fallback for Android Browser, that uses a flash websockets implementation, in case the user has flash installed, but since it detects websockets are supported on the S3, it does not use the fallback.

Did anybody experienced the same kind of problems ? Does anyone know what version of websockets the S3 browser implements ? (even the WebSocket.org echo test fails)

Comment: You should accept an answer if one suits or comment, what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with SGS 3 like you and also we had flash fallback. The problem is that other androids return for us `undefined` when you call `window.WebSocket` BUT SGS3 doesn't. So we solved this issue with `window.WebSocket = undefined;`. So our flash fallback began to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Android's default browser implements the `WebSocket` API, but it's doing nothing. However (at least on my S2+), there's no `CLOSING` property in `WebSocket`, so you could use the following function to detect if WebSockets are actually supported:

```
websocketSupported = function() {
    if(typeof WebSocket === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    return 'CLOSING' in WebSocket.prototype;
} ();
```

Answer (score 0):

However I am very late to answer this question. But still I want to share that none of the ANDROID browser still supports WebSockets. Refer [this](http://caniuse.com/websockets)

I also made a basic PhoneGap app using data pushing using SignalR and tried to run on different ANDROID versions and found that it is working fine on SAMSUNG ACE DUOS, MICROMAX A116 and one very old SAMSUNG model (sorry I can't remember the model number) but it fails on SAMSUNG GALAXY S3.

Comment: The problem is that despite there is no official Websocket Support in the Android Browser before 4.4, Samsung obviously patched the browser in some of its Android devices to support Websockets. Unfortunately the implementation seems to be brocken.